# How do I paint only one side of a mirrored object without effecting the other?

Tags: texture-painting, mirror-modifier

Im creating an avatar and the character im making is supposed to be half and half colors. The issue is, i mirrored the right side of the character so whatever i paint on the right appears on the left and vice versa.

Im wondering if theres a way to texture paint only one side of an object with out it appearing on the other?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Apply the mirror modifier then you can paint each side separately.

Comment: I have the mirror modifier already enabled, im trying to paint only one side of the body without it mirroring to the otherside.

Comment: You say that you have it enabled, but have you applied it? If it's not been applied one side of the mesh doesn't really exist so you can't paint on it directly. Hover the mouse over the modifier in the modifiers panel and hit Ctrl-A to apply it.

Comment: I tried out some other ways i didnt think of before and they worked, apologies for taking up some of your time ^^"

Comment: No problem. Glad you're sorted. It would be helpful for others searching for the same problem if you could explain what you did to get over your own issue. You should be able to add an answer below to your own question.